# How to prevent indent on second line with packed itemize?

Tags: environments, indentation

How to prevent indent on second line with packed itemize instead of itemize? In other words I dont want "Major" to be indented.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage
\newenvironment{packed_itemize}
{\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemindent}{-10pt}
\setlength{\itemsep}{-0.3pt}}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-0.5em}}

\newenvironment{packed_inner_itemize}
{\begin{packed_itemize}}
{\end{packed_itemize}\vspace{0.25em}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
\item\textbf{#1} \hfill #2\null\\
#3 \hfill #4%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{packed_itemize} 
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\end{packed_itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What package provides `packed_itemize`? The example stops with "environment undefined".

Comment: Looking at it closer, just delete `\setlength{\itemindent}{-10pt}` from your `packed_itemize` environment. `packed_inner_itemize` also does nothing different from `packed_itemize` but `\vspace{0.25em}`. You can move the definition of `\ressubheading` out of `packed_inner_itemize` too.

Comment: deleting that line idents both "Name..." and "Major". Is there any way i can bring both of these out -10pt?

Comment: @user26080 See if replacing `\setlength{\itemindent}{-10pt}` with `\setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}`  makes any difference.

Comment: Adding `\hspace*{\itemindent}` _before_ `#3` does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You should adjust the left margin, via `\leftmargini` instead:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage
\newenvironment{packed-itemize}
{\leftmargini=15pt\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{-0.3pt}}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-0.5em}}

\newenvironment{packed_inner-itemize}
{\begin{packed-itemize}}
{\end{packed-itemize}\vspace{0.25em}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
\item\textbf{#1} \hfill #2\null\\\relax
#3 \hfill #4%
}
\begin{document}

\noindent Standard itemize:
\begin{itemize} 
\item{Name of Grad School}\hfill City\\Major \hfill 2010 -- 2012
\item{Name of Grad School}\hfill City\\Major \hfill 2010 -- 2012
\end{itemize}

\noindent New commands:
\begin{packed-itemize} 
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\end{packed-itemize}

\noindent
Some text.
\end{document}
```

I have changed the name of your environment to `packed-itemize` to avoid the `_` symbol, which to my eyes always denotes some mathematics.  Also changed is the addition of a `\relax` after `\\`, to prevent nasty surprises if `#3` begins with a square bracket `[`.

In general it is easier to define modified list environments via the [`enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).  Your example would then use:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{packed-itemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[packed-itemize]{leftmargin=15pt,label=\textbullet}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{\item \textbf{#1}\hfill #2\relax\\\relax #3
\hfill #4}
```